# Bootstrap: JQuery DateTimePicker not displaying dates

Tags: html, css, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement a date-time calendar using Bootstrap, and when I'm using the datetimepicker, no dates or times are being made available to select. The libraries needed for datetimepicker are already downloaded and in the respective folders within the directory.

[image: Example of what I'm getting]

Here is my code:

```html
 <head>
            <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
            <!-- Custom Fonts -->
            <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
            <!-- Theme CSS -->
            <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
            <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]> -->
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js" integrity="sha384-0s5Pv64cNZJieYFkXYOTId2HMA2Lfb6q2nAcx2n0RTLUnCAoTTsS0nKEO27XyKcY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZoaMbDF+4LeFxg6WdScQ9nnR1QC2MIRxA1O9KWEXQwns1G8UNyIEZIQidzb0T1fo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="carPUdatetime"> Date and Time: </label>
               <div class='input-group date form_datetime' data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy - HH:ii" id='carPUdatetime'>
               <input class="form-control" type="text" required/>
               <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
               </span>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
           
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"> .</script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#carPUdatetime').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: @RacilHilan where exactly please?

Comment: According to RacilHilan you need to change your jQuery.
                $('#carPUdatetime>input').datetimepicker();

Answer (score 0):

Move the `id='carPUdatetime'` from the `div` to the `input`:

```
<label for="carPUdatetime"> Date and Time: </label>
   <div class='input-group date form_datetime' data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy - HH:ii">
   <input id='carPUdatetime' class="form-control" type="text" required/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

That's not exactly an answer to your question, but the value of the `for` attribute in the `label` must be an HTML control, not `div`.

Apart from that, the code in your question works fine and the dates are displayed.

If you want to keep the calendar with the `div`, then give the `input` a different `id` from the `div`:

```
<label for="carPUdatetime"> Date and Time: </label>
   <div class='input-group date form_datetime' data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy - HH:ii" id='carPUcalendar'>
   <input id='carPUdatetime' class="form-control" type="text" required/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#carPUcalendar').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to update to this however now my calendar icon is unresponsive and not even part of the calendar shows up

Comment: Yes, because with this change, the calendar is now attached to the `input`, so click inside it and you will get your calendar. If you want to keep the calendar with the `div`, you need to give it a different `id` from the `input` which you used in the `for` attribute` of the `label`. See my  updated answer. Again, the code in your question doesn't have an issue and is working. This answer is only to fix the incorrect `for` attribute in the `label`.

Comment: i still have the same error that the date options are not being displayed in my actual website but on this question they are...

Comment: Yes, but we cannot answer questions about the code on your website which we don't see. We don't have crystal balls. The code that you posted works, so there is nothing to fix. Like I said, the issue in my answer is not related and only to fix the incorrect `label`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you called datepicker on the div and not the input.
Change

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required/>
```

to

```
<input id="testInput" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
```

and update your javascript to

```
$(function () {
  $('#testInput').datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: this just causes my calendar icon to become unresponsive and no calendar pop up shows up